# powershelll Mount-DiskImage "The system cannot find the path specified."

Tags: powershell, mount-diskimage

I have a batch file I'm executing on Windows 10 through the "Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment"

```
powershell Mount-DiskImage ./%WORKSPACE%/W10-LTSB.iso
```

The environment variable WORKSPACE has been checked and contains a valid path that exists as does the file W10-LTSB.iso, however when this command is executed it results in:

```
Mount-DiskImage: The system cannot find the path specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Mount-DiskImage ./CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216/W10-LTSB.iso
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_DiskImage:ROOT/Microsoft/.../MSFT_DiskImage) [Mount-DiskImage], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070003,Mount-DiskImage
```

Everything looks valid and has been checked many times, what does this message mean?

Comment: `./` means that the current directory is used, whatever it is. Maybe c:\windows\system32? Try an absolute path instead.

Comment: Thank you that was the problem, create an answer and I'll tick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a path starts with a dot/period `.`, it [refers to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/fccd0313-0364-45bd-b75c-924fd6a5662f) the current directory. When a shell session starts, its current directory is configuration dependent.

For example, try running a Powershell session. It should default in `c:\Users\<username>`. Run a Powershell as admin and it usually defaults in `C:\WINDOWS\system32`.

When mounting a disk image with a path beginning with a dot

```
powershell Mount-DiskImage ./%WORKSPACE%/W10-LTSB.iso
```

will tell `Mount-DiskImage` to look the file from its current directory's subdir. Should the current directory be unexpected, Powershell's looking the file from wrong a place.

As for a solution, use absolute paths, or make sure the file is located in a path that's available via current directory (whatever it is).